# Go for a ride x Take a walk x Go for a walk

Tags: word-in-context

Translating **go for a ride** from English to Portuguese using Google Translator results in **dar um passeio** (the only translation provided). But translating **dar um passeio** from Portuguese to English results in **take a walk** and **go for a walk** - but not in **go for a ride**.

Can really **go for a ride** be used with the same meaning as **take a walk** or **go for a walk**, I mean, walk around with no specifc destination just to relax, kill time, enjoy the view, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "go for a ride" can't really be used interchangeably with "go for a walk", because you need something to ride in or on: a car, bike, horse, etc.  Idiomatically, you don't go for a ride on your own feet.

However, "go for a ride" can and often does share the connotation of having no particular destination in mind and journeying purely for relaxing, killing time, etc.